# Pine Script 5 - Access data from strategy()

Tags: pine-script-v5

I'm trying to access data from the strategy() function to save this in a variable so I can use this in the script for plotting and or table data. I don't know if this is possible?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=25, margin_short=25)

leverageLong = 100 / margin_long
leverageShort = 100 / strategy.margin_short
```

I tried both `margin_long` & `strategy.margin_short`. Is there a way of accessing this data?

Comment: which 'data' do you want to retrieve ?

Comment: Hi, I like to retrieve the margin_long & margin_short variables that are located within the strategy() function but I don't know if these variables are accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pinescript, the margin_long and margin_short is a fixed percentage.
You can' retrieve it once declare in the 'strategy' statement.
If you want it in a variable, that you will be able to change in the parameter panel on your charte, you can do this :

```
marginLong = input.float(25,"Margin Long")
marginShort = input.float(25,"Margin Short")
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=marginLong, margin_short=marginShort)
```

This way, you will be able to use it after in your code.